# R Shiny: User defined function works well in regular R code but fails inside a shiny function

Tags: r, shiny

I'm very new to Shiny and I'm trying to pass a function which creates aged brackets in a data frame, which I had tested outside Shiny into a shiny app.

Below is the code outside Shiny:

```
# Regular R Code
Aging <- function(data, Transaction.Date){
 if(missing(Transaction.Date)) stop("You forgot to specify Transaction Date")
 Transaction.Date <- deparse(substitute(Transaction.Date))
 data$year <- year(data[,Transaction.Date])
 data$Age <- car::recode(year(data[,Transaction.Date]), "year(Report.Date) = year(Report.Date); year(Report.Date)-1 = year(Report.Date)-1; else = paste(year(Report.Date)-2, 'And Prior')")
 return(data)
}

Debtors <- data.frame(Names = c("John", "Mary", "Charles", "Peter", "David", "Fabian", "Aggrey", "Elizabeth", "Anthony", "Catherine"), Amount = seq(from = 100000, by = 600, length.out = 10), Transaction.Date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2016/1/1"), by = "quarter", length.out = 10))

Report.Date <- max(Debtors$Transaction.Date)

Aged.Data <- Aging(Debtors, Transaction.Date)
```

And below is the Shiny App that I have attempted to create but does not work:

```
library(shiny)
Aging <- function(data, Transaction.Date){
 if(missing(Transaction.Date)) stop("You forgot to specify Transaction Date")
 Transaction.Date <- deparse(substitute(Transaction.Date))
 data$year <- year(data[,Transaction.Date])
 data$Age <- car::recode(year(data[,Transaction.Date]), "year(Report.Date) = year(Report.Date); year(Report.Date)-1 = year(Report.Date)-1; else = paste(year(Report.Date)-2, 'And Prior')")
 return(data)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
dataTableOutput("Aged.Data")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
Data <- reactive({
Debtors <- data.frame(Names = c("John", "Mary", "Charles", "Peter", "David", "Fabian", "Aggrey", "Elizabeth", "Anthony", "Catherine"), Amount = seq(from = 100000, by = 600, length.out = 10), Transaction.Date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2016/1/1"), by = "quarter", length.out = 10))

Report.Date <- max(Debtors$Transaction.Date)
Aged.Data <- Aging(Debtors, Transaction.Date)
})

output$Aged.Data <- renderDataTable(Data())

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The error I get is:

```
in recode term:  else = paste(year(Report.Date)-2, 'And Prior')
message: Error in year(Report.Date) : object 'Report.Date' not found
```

I will really appreciate any assistance with this.

Joseph.

Comment: I had no problem running it, after I included the needed package `lubridate`.

Comment: Thanks, but if you run the shiny code independently after making sure there are no residual objects from the initial 'non-shiny' code, it throws the error I had indicated. Kindly try running only the shiny part in a new r session and confirm if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple scoping issue.

The `Aging` function in the shiny example is in the global scope and there, it refers to `Report.Date`. Scope wise, `Report.Date` can only be accessed from `Aging` if it is either defined in the function itself or if it is also a global variable. This is the case in the non-shiny example.

But in your shiny version, the variable is defined only inside the `server` function. `Aging` and `server` don't share any variables. So the error is indeed, that `Report.Date` does not exist from the global scope perspective.

You have at least three options here:

1. Move the `Aging` function inside the `server` function (as a subfunction) such that `Aging` has access to the scope of `server`.
2. Move `Report.Date` out of the `server` scope into the global scope and change it from `server` using `<<-` instead of `<-`. (Key for assigning variables in a super scope.)
3. Make `Report.Date` a parameter in the function call instead of an out-of-scope variable. Then, inside `server` you can call it with the desired value as `Report.Date`

Based on this simple example, I would say that the third solution is the cleanest one.

If you need some more explanations, feel free to comment.

Comment: Many thanks @K.Rohde. I found solution 2 on moving Report.Date into the global scope to be the neatest in my specific problem. Much appreciated.

Comment: @JosephKigotho And be aware, that global variables are shared between all shiny sessions, i.e. people opening this application. So another user can alter the same `Report.Date` as well.

Comment: following the cautionary note above by @K.Rohde, I tried implementing solution 3 where I successfully rewrote the `Aging` function to include `Report.Date` as an argument. I then added a `dateInput` in the UI to have each user select their unique `Report.Date`. It however seems like I'm still having to resort to the global assignment operator to assign the user input as an argument to the `Aging` function. I have rewritten the new question here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665486/r-shiny-object-input-not-found). I'm looking to avoid overwriting of the `Report.Date` argument.